# How to set Virtualbox centos 7 client to share host vpn

Tags: virtualbox, centos7, vpn

I need to access vpn of host from my virtualbox vm centos.
But search and tried several method failed.

Environment:

- Host: Win10
- VPN: shadowsocks-windows
- Virtual box 5.2
- Client: Centos 7

Answer (score 1):

Search from google, many set virtualbox to use Bridge mode.

Here I use NAT mode and passed.

1. Enable shadowsocks to allow local network connection
2. Set Virtualbox to use NAT network Adapter 
   [image: set network adapter mode]
3. Get virtualbox network adapter ip by run cmd in centos consle:  $ ip route show 
   [image: get virtualbox network adapter ip]
4. Set Centos network proxy to use virtualbox network adapter ip and shadowsocks server port, by default is 1080 
   [image: set vm client network proxy]

Then enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The following looks a good answer to the question:

virtualbox guest os through vpn

https://superuser.com/questions/987150/virtualbox-guest-os-through-vpn